Issue with Creating MSK Cluster Using Crossplane
I'm trying to create an MSK (Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka) cluster using Crossplane, but I'm facing some issues with the configuration and setup. I would appreciate any guidance or troubleshooting help.
What I've Done So Far:
Crossplane Setup:
Installed Crossplane on my Kubernetes cluster using kubectl and helm.
Configured ProviderConfig for AWS using apiVersion: aws.upbound.io/v1beta1.
Goal:
Create an MSK cluster and MSK configuration using Crossplane, by defining XRC (Composite Resource Claim), XRD (Composite Resource Definition), and a Composition.
What I try?

I installed Crossplane on my Kubernetes cluster using kubectl and helm.
Configured the AWS provider using the following ProviderConfig

and i am expecting to get help to create XRD , Compostion, XRC for Crossplane

What issues or error are you getting?
